# jQuery: slide out and slide in the next element and loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to slide out and then slide in the next element and loop.

currently I can slide the element OUT but the next one wont slide in.

This is a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ykzwctoh/31/)

And this is my code:

```
$( "#SLIDE" ).click(function() {
var widths = $('.some').width();


 $(".some")
    .first()
    .animate({ "margin-left": widths }, "slow" )
    .next()
    .animate({ "margin-left": 0 }, "slow" )
    .end();


});
```

Could someone please advise on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this" `$(".some")
    .first()
    .animate({ "margin-left": -widths }, "slow" )
    .next('.some')
    .animate({ "margin-left": -widths }, "slow" )
    .end();
 

});`

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach for your slide.

```js
var click = 1;
$("#SLIDE").click(function() {
  if (click == $(".some").length) {
var widths = 1;
click = 1;
  } else {
var widths = $('.some').width() * click;
  }
  $(".some")
.first()
.animate({
  "margin-left": "-" + widths
}, "slow")
.next()
.animate({
  "margin-left": 0
}, "slow")
.end();

  click += 1;
});
```

```css
#feedTxt {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height:450px;
    width:100%;
}

.some {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="feedTxt">

    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 1</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>



    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 2</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>


    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 3</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>


    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 4</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>

</div>

<button id="SLIDE">Peress to slide</button>
```

Here is the working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykzwctoh/37/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This wouldn't loop I'm afraid. it will keep going even if there are no elements left.

Comment: I much prefer this method. do you know how I can go back to the first element once it's reached the end of the elements?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one helps you.

```js
$(function() {
  // count your slide elements
  var elementCount = $('.some').length;
  // width of the first element
  var width = $('.some').first().width();
  // full width of all elements
  var fullWidth = elementCount*width;
  // scroll left value
  var scrollLeft = width;

  // update values after resizing
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    width = $('.some').first().width();
    scrollLeft = width;
    fullWidth = elementCount*width;
    $("#feedTxt").scrollLeft(0);
  });

  
  $("#SLIDE").click(function() {

    // if full width smaller or equal to your scroll left, than scroll to the beginning
    if((fullWidth) <= scrollLeft) {
      scrollLeft = 0;
    }

    // animate scroll left
    $("#feedTxt").animate({scrollLeft: scrollLeft}, 800);

    // if the full width not equal to scroll left, add width to scrollLeft
    if((fullWidth) !== scrollLeft) {
      scrollLeft += width;
    }
  }); 
});
```

```css
#feedTxt {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height:450px;
    width:100%;
}

.some {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="feedTxt">

    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 1</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>



    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 2</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>


    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 3</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>


    <div class="some">
        <h1>title 4</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>

</div>

<button id="SLIDE">Press to slide</button>
```